# IntelliJ - How to find with any character in all project's source code?

Tags: intellij-idea

I just switch to IntelliJ from Eclipse.

Let's you know, I already know to find all project's source in IntelliJ is `Ctrl-Shift-F`.

When I use eclipse, if I want to find a string like "accessVariable = configuration" and I just know 2 word "access" and "configuration", I just need to type "access*configuration".

Any things like that in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable **Regex** checkbox and use `.*`: `access.*configuration`.